# Trying to store information from JOptionPane into array but array keeps looping

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, joptionpane

I'm writing a program mostly using JOptionPane to store 5 dogs in an array from the information typed in the JOptionPane but the information is not going to the array and the program keeps looping

```
import javax.swing. JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class DogKennelGui2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        double[] dogStaying = new double [5]; // Stores dog breeds  
        String dogBreed, daysHeld; 
        double price1 = 25; 
        double price2 = 50; 
        double price3 = 75; 
        final double SALES_TAX =.07;  
        final double FED_TAX = .14; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "WELCOME TO METROPOLITAN DOG KENNEL",
                        "METROPOLITAN DOG KENNEL",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
        int i=0;
        while(i<5) {
            try{
                dogStaying[i] = Double.parseDouble (
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Enter the breed of dogs you" + 
                        " will be leaving with us today:"));
                i++;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog ( null,
                    "The max number of dogs per customer is five:");
            }
        }
    }
}
// Why does it continue looping?
```

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: I notice I had to type it in 5 times now I have another question now how can I use the information to multiply it to the price variable?

Comment: @Neo: Please do clarify the question a bit more clearly, as to which variable is suppose to get multiplied by which index of an array ( A little confusing how a dog breed can be of type `double` ).

Comment: @nIcEcOw now my code keeps looping again but I wanted to use the strings stored whether they type 1 string or 5 and multiply the amount of strings by the price based on the amount of strings typed